# Creating iterable-based alternative to the filter() method of JavaScript arrays

Tags: javascript, loops, iterator

I am a beginner reading the chapter Iterators from the book

> JavaScript: The Definitive Guide

I am not able to understand the `next()` method in the below example from book which is about Creating iterable-based alternative to the filter() method of JavaScript arrays.

```
// Return an iterable object that filters the specified iterable,
// iterating only those elements for which the predicate returns true
function filter(iterable, predicate) {
    let iterator = iterable[Symbol.iterator]();
    return { // This object is both iterator and iterable
        [Symbol.iterator]() {
            return this;
        },
        next() {
            for(;;) {
                let v = iterator.next();
                if(v.done || predicate(v.value)) {
                    return v;
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Let's test this function with an array.

```
let a = [1,2,3,4,5]
let iter = filter(a, x => x>3) // Call the function

// Lets check the returned object of iter.next() method
iter.next() // {value: 4, done: false}
iter.next() // {value: 5, done: false}
iter.next() // {value: undefined, done: true}
```

I am completely confused about the `next()` method here. Please help me in understanding it.

Also, I am not able to understand that... the `next()` method contains an infinite for loop. But what it makes it break that loop. There is no condition like that here.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also, I am not able to understand that... the next() method contains an infinite for loop. But what it makes it break that loop. There is no condition like that here.

`return` breaks the loop.

> I am completely confused about the next() method here. Please help me in understanding it.

Here's what it's doing:

1. It calls `next` to get the next result object, which it stores in `v`.
2. If `v.done` is truthy, it returns `v` (breaking the loop). This means the iterator has reached the end of its sequence.
3. If `v.done` is falsy, it calls `predicate` passing in `v.value`; if `predicate` returns a truthy value, `next` returns `v` (breaking the loop).

So the result is that the iterator returned by that `filter` function will iterate the values that the predicate returns a truthy value for, and will return a result object with `done` set to a truthy value when it reaches the end of the input interable.

---

I haven't read the recent editions of the book (I bought mine something like 15 years ago), but my guess is that the given code is meant to show how you would use an iterator explicitly, and later Flanagan will introduce `for-of` and generator functions, which provide a simpler means of doing that `filter`:

```
function* filter(iterable, predicate) {
    for (const element of iterable) {
        if (predicate(element)) {
            yield element;
        }
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function* filter(iterable, predicate) {
    for (const element of iterable) {
        if (predicate(element)) {
            yield element;
        }
    }
}

let a = [1,2,3,4,5];
let iter = filter(a, x => x>3); // Call the function

// Lets check the returned object of iter.next() method
console.log(iter.next()); // {value: 4, done: false}
console.log(iter.next()); // {value: 5, done: false}
console.log(iter.next()); // {value: undefined, done: true}
```

I went back and forth between implicit (`for-of`, generators) and explicit in Chapter 6 of my recent book [*JavaScript: The New Toys*](https://thenewtoys.dev). I found interleaving them was the best I could do to help get the concepts but also the details across.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation. It helped me a lot in understanding. I would love to read the book and increase my knowledge :)

Comment: I just wanted to ask one more general question. How does the spread operator works with the iterable object that is being returned. For example `[...filter(a, x => x>3)]` would return `[4, 5]`. I mean.. how do they work behind the scenes.

Comment: Do they keep calling the function and if `v` is returned, it stores `v.value` in my array. And.. it keeps calling this continuously till it reach `v.value === undefined` or `done === true`

Comment: @RakeshPoddar - When you use spread in an array literal (`[...something]`), it gets the iterator from `something` and calls it repeatedly, storing the returned values in the new array, until it sees the `done` flag. (Note: `...` isn't an operator. Operators can't do what spread and rest syntax do.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing my doubt. I too got some instinct that it must work this way but my terminology of language was cleared fantastically by you.